# Retrieving data from a Table

Tags: sql

I have a table with sample data as shown below

The table has 4 columns and out of which multiple records can have similar entries for the first 3 columns

The 4th column is a date value which is unique for every record

```
A,  A11,  1,  1900-01-01
A,  A11,  1,  2000-01-01
B,  B11,  0,  1900-01-01
C,  C11,  0,  1900-09-01
C,  C11,  0,  2011-01-01
```

(Columns separated by comma )

Now as you can see for A A11 1 (combination of 3 columns) there are 2 entries.

So in my final result set i should get A A11 1 2000-01-01 (max date) as the output for this entry.

Please advice

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3):

You want a GROUP BY:

```
select c1, c2, c3, max(c4)
from your_table
group by c1, c2, c3
```

where `c1` through `c4` are your column names.